# LinqToDB How to add AccessToken to database connection

Tags: c#, access-token, service-principal

I need to use `ServicePrincipal` to authenticate to SQL server using `LinqToDB`. I followed [this microsoft article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-SQL-Database/Azure-AD-Service-Principal-authentication-to-SQL-DB-Code-Sample/ba-p/481467) to test that the setup is correct. However this example uses `System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlConnection` class that has an `AccessToken` property so it can add the `AccessToken` to the connection.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    conn.AccessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    // ...
}
```

I am using `LinqToDB` and trying to figure out where can I add the `AccessToken` obtained from `AD`. The `DataConnection` ([source](https://linq2db.github.io/api/LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.html)) does not have an `AccessToken` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is interested here is the solution.

1. Create a connection factory class, adding the Access Token in the connection object, like so:

   ```
   public IDbConnection MyConnectionFactory()
   {
       ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId,ClientSecret);
       AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
       AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(TargetUrl, clientCredential).Result;
       SqlConnection MyDataConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
       MyDataConnection.AccessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

       return MyDataConnection;
   }
   ```
2. create a data provider for your database:

   ```
       IDataProvider MyDataProvider = new SqlServerDataProvider("SqlServer", SqlServerVersion.v2008);
   ```
3. Pass these into the constructor for DataConnection

`using (var db = new DataConnection(MyDataProvider, MyConnectionFactory))`